# luasoket http request got "connection refused"

Tags: lua, luasocket

I am trying to use luasocket to make http "GET" request to "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"  , it yields a "connection refused" , while I can access this URL from the the web browser either use python httplib.
    I doubted it is because the HTTPS protocal ,  but if i replace url with "https//www.google.com" , it works ok.
    so any1 has ideas on what the problem is ?  much thx for ur answers

This is the code:

```
local http = require("socket.http")

URL = "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"
local response, httpCode, header = http.request(URL)

print(response, httpCode, header)
```

Comment: You are using a http request, for a https url, try it with `local https = require "ssl.https"`